# Uncaught TypeError: url.format is not a function at ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js

Tags: reactjs

```
"react-dev-utils": "12.0.1",
"react-hot-loader": "4.13.1",
"webpack": "5.66.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "4.7.3",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "4.1.1",
"workbox-webpack-plugin": "6.4.2"
```

"react": "18.2.0",
"antd": "5.6.4",

Then take errors：
Uncaught TypeError: url.format is not a function
at ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js (webpackHotDevClient.js:60:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at **webpack_exec** (xlsx|stream:1:1)
at xlsx|stream:1:1
at **webpack_require**.O (chunk loaded:23:1)
at xlsx|stream:1:1
at webpackJsonpCallback (jsonp chunk loading:558:1)
at main.çbundle.js:1:83

How to resolve this error?

Comment: You can try the following steps:
1. remove package-lock.json
2. npm install
3. npm update
4. make sure all other plugins are compatible with your react version.

Upload your package.json package so that community can further assist you.